# How to use Fragment in android activity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, retrofit2

I have an news app where I have used Retrofit library to call the api and the display the news using card view in recycler view. I also implement, when a user will click on a card the whole news will display on a new activity using webview. Now I want to do the same work using Fragment. I an totally new with fragment , that's why don't have the proper knowledge about fragment. If someone can give me the idea that how I can implement that and also resource or note about fragment that will be very helpful for me. Here I am providing the code of my MainActivity , adapter and webview activity.

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var adapter: NewsAdapter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        getNews()
    }

    private fun getNews() {
        val news :Call<News> = NewsSeversis.newsIntence.getHeadlines("in",1)
        news.enqueue(object :Callback<News>{
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<News>, response: Response<News>) {
                //here response is a News response
                val news:News?=response.body()
                if (news!=null){
                    Log.d("response",news.toString())
                    adapter= NewsAdapter(news.articles)
                    newsList.adapter=adapter
                    newsList.layoutManager=LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity)
                    Log.d("itemcount","${(newsList.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager).itemCount}")
                    Log.d("itemcount2", "${(newsList.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager).findFirstVisibleItemPosition()}")


                }
            }
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<News>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.d("response","error occur",t)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Adapter

```
class NewsAdapter (val artical: List<Artical>):RecyclerView.Adapter<NewsAdapter.articalViewHolder>(){
   inner class articalViewHolder(itemView: View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): articalViewHolder {
        val view:View=LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_layout,parent,false)
        return articalViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: articalViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val articals:Artical=artical[position]
        holder.itemView.apply {
            newsTitle.text=articals.title
            newsDescription.text=articals.description
            Glide.with(context).load(articals.urlToImage).into(newsImage)
            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
                val intent=Intent(context,DetailsWebview::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("EXTRA_URL",articals.url)
                Log.d("url",articals.url)
                context.startActivity(intent)
            }
        }
    }
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
       return artical.size
    }
}
```

Activity code for the webview

```
class DetailsWebview : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_details_webview)
        val url :String?=intent.getStringExtra("EXTRA_URL")
        if (url !=null){
            Log.d("DataFlow", "URL received: $url")
            detailsWebview.settings.javaScriptEnabled=true
            detailsWebview.settings.userAgentString="Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9; CPH1909) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.82 Mobile Safari/537.36"
            detailsWebview.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
                override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
                    progressBar.visibility=View.GONE
                    detailsWebview.visibility=View.VISIBLE
                }
            }
            detailsWebview.loadUrl(url)
        }else  Log.d("DataFlow", "No URL received")
    }
}
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/overview

Comment: can you help me a little bit how to implement what I am trying to do

Comment: Have you create your fragment?

Comment: Only one blank fragment

Answer (score 0):

For example activity inside **fragment** (java)

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:orientation="vertical">

<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
    android:backgroundTint="#007FE4"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
    app:tabTextColor="#DFDFDF"
    app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_color_select"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
    android:id="@+id/view_pager2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

MainActivity.java

```
 private ActivityMainBinding binding;
private Context context = this;
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager2 viewPager2;
private ViewPagerFragmentAdapter adapter;

// array for tab labels
private String[] tabs = new String[]{"Video", "Image"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    View view = binding.getRoot();
    setContentView(view);

    // call function to initialize views
    viewPager2Init();

    // bind and set tabLayout to viewPager2 and set labels for every tab
    new TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, viewPager2, (tab, position) -> {
        tab.setText(tabs[position]);
    }).attach();

    // set default position to 1 instead of default 0
    viewPager2.setCurrentItem(0, false);
}


private void viewPager2Init() {
    // initialize tabLayout
    tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    // initialize viewPager2
    viewPager2 = findViewById(R.id.view_pager2);
    // create adapter instance
    adapter = new ViewPagerFragmentAdapter(this);
    // set adapter to viewPager2
    viewPager2.setAdapter(adapter);

    // remove default elevation of actionbar

}

// create adapter to attach fragments to viewpager2 using FragmentStateAdapter
private class ViewPagerFragmentAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {

    public ViewPagerFragmentAdapter(@NonNull FragmentActivity fragmentActivity) {
        super(fragmentActivity);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new VideoFragment();
            case 1:
                return new ImageFragment();
        }
        return new VideoFragment(); //chats fragment
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return tabs.length;
    }
}
```

ImageFragment.java

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_image, container, false);

    //changeStatusBarColor();
    return view;
}
```